# What's the best method to do end to end test in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, frontend, end-to-end

I'm a beginner on this technology.

I'm using Angular 5  as front end for a simple application I'm working on, I want to learn how to use test end to end in angular5, I found that there are many tools to reach it.

There is Jasmin, Protractor...

It's seems a little bit difficult to work with, but I want some advice:

What's the best tool for end to end test?

Do you know any helpful links with simple explanation on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is THE best tool for end to end test, but can give out some advice basing on my little experience.

To my knowledge, end to end test (e2e) is just a little bit like blackbox test, we can run a program to simulate a human being to use keyboard or mouse to operate the system. So there is no particular e2e tool that just work for Angular, that means, any tool is good at e2e test can be used to test Angular.

But be careful, there is no easy tool for e2e test. As you are building an auto machine to replace human, you need to write down every single test case in some language, you need to specify the operation steps and expectations, and you need to test the test machine itself. Even for the very basic login screen, you need to write down test cases to let it know where is the username input field, where is the password input field, and how to click the login button, plus, remember to save the cookies the server send to you. Only after successfully login, and save cookies correctly can you go to next step. All these test for test machine will cost time, but as you like.

For tools, I used `Casper.js` before, which you can google. It include `phantomjs` at bottom. Some people may like `Selenium`, and some others may choose `Nightwatch`. But none of these tools are easy. The best way is to try to download and write some simple test case to try by yourself.

UPDATE: `Protractor` should be the best tool for `Angular` apps.

Comment: Thank you so much for these useful information , so i'll do it as you said , thank you again for taking time to write all of this :)

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is definitely an option to write end to end tests for Angular.js applications. This framework was born as a result of the inabilities of Selenium to handle JavaScript frameworks such as Angular.js. It is an end to end testing framework to specifically test Angular and Angular JS applications. It has built in functions to identify different types of elements in these applications. One of the coolest feature of the framework is its support for parallel testing, where you can run several browser instances simultaneously.

Although protractor has good features to do web automation it does have its limitations. It only supports JavaScript and automating Angular.js applications. It does not support mobile apps and does not provide great support to other JavaScript frameworks. This is especially important to consider if your team decides to use a a different JavaScript library in the near future.

Currently, I am working on a tool called [Testim](https://testim.io/) that helps anyone build robust automation suites for Angular.js, Vue.js, Ember.js, React.js and other JavaScript frameworks.

Testim is an AI based web automation tool for authoring, execution and maintenance of tests focused on GUI testing and end to end testing. We have an AI underneath the hood which analyzes all the DOM objects in real time and extracts all the object trees and properties. Based on this it creates a list of location strategies. Based on this list it chooses the best way to locate an element. This strategy is called Dynamic locator strategy. This how our AI works. It is the algorithm we implemented. The more tests your run the smarter it becomes to make your tests more stable.

You can check out the below blog posts to know more.
https://blog.testim.io/bringing-simplicity-to-authoring-and-execution-of-automated-tests/